how do i fix incorrect mysql library version in ruby on rails?
im trying to make an application that connect to a mysql databse, but whatever i do, i kept making zero progress because i cant get past this line
 Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 10.8.8 but the client library is 3.3.8.

ive tried uninstalling/installing, installing anything i can think off on mysql and everything else i found online, but that never goes away. i know for a fact i have the most recent ruby version as well as mysql.
after uninstalling the gem and reinstalling it, nothing changed. ive tried putting a lib files from mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip into ruby/bin but nohting changed. i tried installing everything mysql related and playing with the config, nothing changed

Seems like it might be a known issue: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1348
